# Prometheus query to detect <no data> result

Tags: prometheus, promql

This question has been asked in this issue as well: https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/issues/3264. But I don't see it being directly answered. 
I was wondering if is there any way I can detect if the output of a PromQL query is

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for something similar to [VictoriaMetrics MetricsQL](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html) `default` operator:

`default` binary operator. q1 default q2 fills gaps in q1 with the corresponding values from q2.

[image]
[image]